# Prototype Ajax Object not actually making request in IE 8

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, jsp, prototypejs

I have a JSP page with the following javascript code:

```
var refreshAjax = {};
function refreshDataOnClickHandler()
    {
        Event.stopObserving($("refreshdata"), "click", refreshDataOnClickHandler);
        refreshAjax = new Ajax.Request("/Locator",
                            {method: "get",
                            onSuccess: onRefreshDataSuccessHandler,
                            onFailure: onRefreshDataFailureHandler,
                            parameters: {
                                            serviceCenter: $("servicecenterselect").getValue(),
                                            action: "RefreshData"
                                        }
                            });
    }

function onRefreshDataSuccessHandler(response)
    {
        $("dashboardmessage").update("Data Refreshed.");
        $("mapRefresh").src = "Images/RefreshData.png";
        refreshAllStopsAndTrucks();
        Event.observe($("refreshdata"), "click", refreshDataOnClickHandler);
    }

Event.observe($("refreshdata"), "click", refreshDataOnClickHandler);
```

The $("refreshdata") resolves to an anchor tag.
"/Locator" resolves to a Java Servlet.
I'm using IE 8.
I'm using Prototype 1.6.1.

The first time I load the page and click "refreshdata" the Servlet is called correctly and I get the expected response.  Every other time I click the "refreshdata" anchor the Javascript seems to go through the steps of making the call and even indicates that it gets a response.  However, the servlet is never actually called.  No response is actually sent.

The only way to get it to work correctly again is to shut down IE 8 and restart it.

This works correctly on Chrome and Firefox.  Does anyone know what strangeness of the IE browser is keeping this from working in IE?

Comment: Why do you remove and then re-add the event handler, rather than just leaving the handler there?

Comment: Because if it takes a couple of seconds to get a response my users like to have a clickfest on the link.  I've even changed the link to indicate that it is waiting for a request and they still click-click-click...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE is probably caching the result of the Ajax GET request.

If you want to always get the latest data from the server, you should either

- Use a POST
- Add some random value as a request parameter

Some relevant links:

- http://ajaxian.com/archives/ajax-ie-caching-issue
- http://greenash.net.au/thoughts/2006/03/an-ie-ajax-gotcha-page-caching/
- http://www.codecouch.com/2009/01/how-to-stop-internet-explorer-from-caching-ajax-requests/